# What does "rolling" mean in this context

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> Hazard Reporting - XX% of Sites compliant to monthly KPI target and ***rolling*** 12-month average

Wider context: https://i.snipboard.io/b1xnmV.jpg (it's about Occupational Health and Safety system of a certain company)

Note: The writing might not be the most grammatically correct.

Answer (score 2):

In finance, a rolling (or moving) average is one which is calculated over a fixed number of previous data points. For example if the average is revised monthly, the January 2021 average would be calculated on data from January 2020 to January 2021, and the February 2021 average with data from February 2020 to February 2021.

> In financial applications a simple moving average (SMA) is the
> unweighted mean of the previous *k* data-points.

[Moving average (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average)

Comment: Data for what exactly?
Is my case financial one?

Comment: @theguyfromtheworld - monthly KPI target, I expect.

Comment: Does it mean that the sites are compliant to both the monthly KPI target and Rolling 12-month average, or that the Rolling 12-month average should be inserted here?

Comment: @theguyfromtheworld the original quote looks like it means they are compliant with both.

Answer (score 2):

A 12-month rolling average means that 12 months for which the average is calculated can begin at any month and end 11 months later.

It is an accounting term. The periods could be weeks, years, or months, typically.

They don't have to be, for example, January to December. They can start or end anywhere as long as twelve months is used.

March to February could be used, for example.

Comment: "March to February could be used." and the next average would be April to March, and so on.

Comment: Why is the next one April to March? Shouldn't it be March to February again, since the previous one ended in February? Also, I should translate this word/idiom/phrase, but I don't know how. Maybe you can help me on why this "rolling" word is used here? What is the semantic root of "rolling" used here?

Comment: @theguyfromtheworld - A 12 month rolling or moving average moves forward each month. Imagine a rolling wheel.

Comment: It's not so much that March to Feb could be used, that date range will be used and each monthly report will have those dates rolling forwards. January's report will have a KPI for December, and rolling KPI for Jan to Dec. February's report will have KPI for January and rolling KPI for Feb to Jan. March will then have Feb, and March to Feb and so on.